# My Follower's Body is Not Visible, But Follower Still With Me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am playing the Skyrim Dragonborn DLC. I am on the Final Descent quest. My companion Serana went completely invisible.

It was a battle with a ton of dreadlord Draugrs. We managed to kill them all. She even spawned a draugr as her own, but during the heat of the battle her body disappeared but she is still with me in spirit.

I tried saving and restarting the game still same problem. I do not know if this is only limited to Serana. Serana is still with me and attacking things that are hostile. Just not visible.

Here is what it looks like.
[image]

Has anyone encountered this strange bug? What can be done to resolve it?

Comment: Try using `resurrect 1` on her in the console, followed by `disable`, `enable` if that doesn't work. Also try sending her off and waiting 30+ days before returning to her.

Comment: It could reset her. Don't forget to add 1 after resurrect so she doesn't lose any items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `resurrect 1` on her in the console, followed by `disable`, `enable` if that doesn't work. Also try sending her off and waiting 30+ days before returning to her.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a temporary glitch or a permanent glitch, I'd try taking out the disk and looking for signs of scratching, I'd also shut down My consol

Comment: Your welcome! :D